# Does Magento save the data order even it was canceled or failed?

Tags: magento2, orders, payment-methods, order-status

I am integrating a payment gateway the test mode is working fine.
But the payment method provider asked for to save order details(failure order during checkout/cancel order during checkout/success order) in database.

Does Magento save these types of data already ? or i need to create custom module for this ?

Answer (score 0):

**PAYMENT SUCCESS:**

Once your payments gets success, payment method will return success param, so the order is created with success status. **Event**: `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

**PAYMENT FAILED/CANCELED:**

Once your payment gets failed or canceled, the payment method will return failed/canceled param, so the order is created too with failed/canceled status. **Event**: `order_cancel_after`

For more informations, see :

- `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/SaveOrder.php`
- `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php`
- `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Failure.php`